# Dynamically choose between output file to write

Tags: c++, ofstream

I have a `Matrix` class and a `std::vector<Matrix>`. I also have 3 stages of calculation and each stage produces a `std::vector<Matrix>` and I have to write these vectors of Matrix to `stage1.txt`,`stage2.txt` and `stage3.txt`. I have written a function for this which will take `stage` number as a parameter and output the vectors of Matrix to corresponding files. Currently my code looks like this:

```
void writeTrianglePointsToFile(int stage){
            std::vector <Matrix> stageTriangles;

            if(stage == 1) stageTriangles = stage1Triangles;
            else if(stage == 2) stageTriangles = stage2Triangles;
            else if(stage == 3) stageTriangles = stage3Triangles;

            for(int i = 0 ; i < stageTriangles.size() ; i++){
                int rows = stageTriangles[i].getMatrixRows() - 1; // discard last row
                int columns = stageTriangles[i].getMatrixColumns();
                for(int j = 0 ; j < columns ; j++){
                    for(int k = 0 ; k < rows ; k++){
                        if(stage == 1){
                            stage1OutputFile << std::fixed << std::setprecision(7) << std::showpoint << stageTriangles[i].matrix[k][j];
                            if(k != rows - 1) stage1OutputFile << " ";
                        } else if(stage == 2){
                            stage2OutputFile << std::fixed << std::setprecision(7) << std::showpoint << stageTriangles[i].matrix[k][j];
                            if(k != rows - 1) stage2OutputFile << " ";
                        } else if(stage == 3){
                            stage3OutputFile << std::fixed << std::setprecision(7) << std::showpoint << stageTriangles[i].matrix[k][j];
                            if(k != rows - 1) stage3OutputFile << " ";
                        }
                    }
                    if(stage == 1) stage1OutputFile << "\n";
                    else if(stage == 2) stage2OutputFile << "\n";
                    else if(stage == 3) stage3OutputFile << "\n";
                }
                if(stage == 1) stage1OutputFile << "\n";
                else if(stage == 2) stage2OutputFile << "\n";
                else if(stage == 3) stage3OutputFile << "\n";
            }
        }
```

Here `stage1Triangles`,`stage2Triangles` and `stage3Triangles` have been declared and computed elsewhere. `stage1OutputFile`,`stage2OutputFile` and `stage3OutputFile` are all `std::ofstream`.

As you can see, the code looks rather ugly, especially inside the nested `for` loop. **How can I redirect output to the desired file dynamically so that I don't have to deal with them in `if-else` blocks?** I want something similar to this:

```
// declare a stageTriangles and ofstream pair
if(stage == 1) set the pair to stage1Triangles and stage1OutputFile
else if(stage == 2) set the pair to stage2Triangles and stage2OutputFile
else if(stage == 3) ...
```

I tried:

```
std::ofstream stageOutputFile;

            if(stage == 1){
                stageTriangles = stage1Triangles;
                stageOutputFile = stage1OutputFile;
            }
```

but it produces an error. What am I doing wrong and how can I do it efficiently?

Comment: Just change `stageOutputFile` to a pointer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to use some type of inderection.

Pointer:

```
 std::ofstream *stageOutputFile;

 if (stage == 1) {
     stageOutputFile = &stage1OutputFile;
 }

 *stageOutputFile << ...;
```

Array:

```
std::ofstream& stageOutputFile[] = {stage1OutputFile, stage2OutputFile, stage3OutputFile};

stageOutputFile[stage] << ...
```

Or some other method...

Answer (score 4):

I will try to point you in the general direction:

## Create a general function

This function can print any `std::vector<Matrix>` to any [std::ostream](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream). `std::ostream` is the base class of all output streams. Could be something like `void PrintListOfMatrices(const std::vector<Matrix> &matrices, std::ostream &output) {...}`

## Call it for each pair of vector and output:

```
PrintListOfMatrices(stage1Triangles, stage1OutputFile);
PrintListOfMatrices(stage2Triangles, stage2OutputFile);
PrintListOfMatrices(stage3Triangles, stage3OutputFile);
```

Answer (score 1):

I would consider using a lambda to create a reference to stageTriangles (you made a copy in your code, might be a large data structure) and stageOutputFile.

A reference is preferable over a pointer, since the objects are not optional. This code will fail, if the pointer to the stageTriangle or the output file is `NULL`.

```
void writeTrianglePointsToFile(int stage) {
    auto getStageTriangles = [&](int stage) {
        if (stage == 1) {
            return stage1Triangles;
        } else if (stage == 2) {
            return stage2Triangles;
        } else if (stage == 3) {
            return stage3Triangles;
        }
    };
    auto getStageOutputFile = [&](int stage) {
        if (stage == 1) {
            return stage1OutputFile;
        } else if (stage == 2) {
            return stage2OutputFile;
        } else if (stage == 3) {
            return stage3OutputFile;
        }
    };

    const auto& stageTriangles = getStageTriangles(stage);
    const auto& stageOutputFile = getStageOutputFile(stage);

    for (const auto& stageTriangle : stageTriangles) {
        int rows = stageTriangle.getMatrixRows() - 1;  // discard last row
        int columns = stageTriangle.getMatrixColumns();
        for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++) {
            for (int k = 0; k < rows; k++) {
                stageOutputFile << std::fixed << std::setprecision(7) << std::showpoint << stageTriangle.matrix[k][j];
                if (k != rows - 1)
                    stageOutputFile << " ";
            }
            stageOutputFile << "\n";
        }
        stageOutputFile << "\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: Between the ``auto`` and ``pointer`` approach, which one is preferable? @schorsch312

Comment: I changed form `pointer` to `reference`. C++ can deduce the type using `auto`.  `auto` reduces duplications (DRY principle).  `const auto& stageTriangles = getStageTriangles(stage);` is equivalent to `const std::vector <Matrix>& stageTriangles = getStageTriangles(stage);`